# Create a file and put it into a folder - Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

is there a way to change the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p new/{css,img,js}
touch index.html style.css nav.js && subl index.html style.css nav.js
```

that it puts the created files into the created folders and then open it with Sublime-Text?

Thx...

Comment: Just include the path `touch new/index.html` etc.

Comment: totally obvious :)... thx very much

Answer (score 1):

Change the filenames into the full relative path:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -p new/{css,img,js}
touch new/{css,img,js}/index.html new/{css,img,js}/style.css new/{css,img,js}/nav.js && subl new/{css,img,js}/index.html new/{css,img,js}/style.css new/{css,img,js}/nav.js
```